# Problems with alternate input of different types of variables using BufferedReader

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand how the System.in input works in java and I created some input-output code. My aim is to display everything that was inputted into the console, even when there are different types of variables (e.g. String, int) alternately in the input.
When I input data line by line, and press Enter after each line - the output is right.
However, if I copy-paste the whole input into the console the code stops after the first iteration of the last for loop and waits for Enter.
What can I do to make it work without the Enter?

Here is the code using BufferedReader + parsing Strings (I also tried with Scanner but the result is the same).

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{     
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String inString;

        inString = input.readLine();
        int test = Integer.parseInt(inString);
        System.out.println(test);
        for (int t=0; t<test; t++){                                     
            inString = input.readLine();
            int cities = Integer.parseInt(inString);
            HashMap<String, Integer> cityMap = new HashMap<>();
            System.out.println(cities);
            for (int c=1; c<=cities; c++){                              
                inString = input.readLine();
                System.out.println(inString);
                cityMap.put(inString, c);                                   
                inString = input.readLine();
                int connections = Integer.parseInt(inString);
                System.out.println(connections);
                for (int i=0; i<connections; i++){
                    inString = input.readLine();
                    String [] parts = inString.split("\\s+");
                    System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) + " ");
                    System.out.print(Integer.parseInt(parts[1]) + "\n");
                }
            }
            inString = input.readLine();
            int routes = Integer.parseInt(inString);
            System.out.println(routes);
            for (int i=0; i<routes; i++){
                inString = input.readLine();
                String [] parts = inString.split("\\s+");
                System.out.println(parts[0] + " " + parts[1]);
            }
        }
}
```

And the input I try is:

```
1
4
london
2
2 1
3 3
berlin
3
1 1
3 1
4 4
paris
3
1 3
2 1
4 1
prague
2
2 4
3 1
2
london prague
berlin prague
```

The last line gets displayed only after I press Enter.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand right what are you trying to say, but if you want that the console should show automatically an input that you've paste into it and not hit the enter key, I'm not sure, but I believe this is imposible because every console works like this, you put some input and after that you hit a key :)

Comment: When I paste the input into the console the program starts reading the input at once and giving the output - up to the line "london prague" and then waits only for Enter - after Enter the last line gets printed out.

Answer (score 0):

Make your text like Line \n Line. I mean, after each line you paste into the console, put a \n :)

Comment: It only results in an error when parsing an Int. I'm just wondering if there is any way to do it without modifications in input.